# Obfuscating server keys for automated login

Tags: encryption, key-management

**Problem statement:**

I want to make private keys / passwords / cryptographic secrets of some kind available to an unattended automated process, but make it difficult for an attacker with access to the system to steal them. Doing all this in software, no smart cards or HSMs.

---

As far as I know, this is a difficult and unsolved problem. For example, AFAIK, Tomcat doesn't even bother and just stores the server TLS private key in the clear. Also there's this question:

[automated decryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101653/automated-decryption)

with the accepted answer:

> What you're asking for is impossible.

---

In the crypto toolkit and product code bases that I work with every day (which will remain unnamed) we have an accepted solution, as I described in [this answer or iot.stackexchange.com](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/2062/4082):

> With traditional servers, the only real solution that I'm aware of is to derive an AES key from some sort of "hardware fingerprint" built by combining serial numbers of all the hardware devices. Then use that AES key to encrypt the credentials. A process running on the same server can reconstruct the AES key and decrypt the credentials, but once you extract the file from the server, it's essentially un-decryptable.

@Gilles took objection to my answer, hence why I'm asking this question to try and learn something.

I am aware that this is obfuscation at best and I'm not claiming that it's a great solution, but I'm not aware of a better one. I am aware of:

- Windows DPAPI, which AFAIK does essentially the same thing by fingerprinting your user account rather than hardware.
- OS keychains, although I thought they needed a human-at-keyboard to enter a password at bootup.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you accept a solution that use a raspberry pi installed with a software based key management software with strict access control and lock it in a vault? There is no smart cards or HSM but a machine you need to lock up.

Comment: @2awm366 You're basically building a poor-man's HSM, right? That is essentially the solution that I suggest in my linked answer, but here I'm trying to ask only about solutions for protecting it in place.

Comment: Ops, sorry. I didn't read the whole answer. My bad.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a whole lot more that can be done. Any 'solution' that I can think of is basically some variation of obsfurcation and something that an attacker with root access to your server would be able to easily replicate. Interesting thought though, want to see what others come up with.